# Разница в инициализации объектов temp1 и temp2

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, инициализация

Оба объекта появляются на форме, для temp1 работает как слот createNewSet() так и connect. Для _firstSet ни то ни другое не работает.
Поля класса Cows:

```
class Cows : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
    Cows(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Cows();
private:
    Ui::CowsClass ui;
    estimatedSet* _firstSet;
    QList<estimatedSet*> * _otherSets;
};
```

В конструкторе класса Cows инициализирую объекты класса estimatedSet:

```
Cows::Cows(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    estimatedSet * temp1 = new estimatedSet(this);
    estimatedSet temp2 = new estimatedSet(this);
    _firstSet = &temp2;
    temp1.last()->createNewSet();
    connect(temp1, SIGNAL(fillComplete()), this, SLOT(prepareShift()));
}
```

Comment: Как у Вас скомпилировался код с инициализацией temp2?

Comment: @alexolut, компилятор не выдает никакой ошибки. В отладчике я вижу созданный объект. Работаю с qt через vs-addin в vs 2015.

Comment: Здесь похоже опечатка: estimatedSet temp2 = new estimatedSet(this); (temp2 - локальная переменная, а не указатель.) Соответственно, после выхода из конструктора объект на который указывает  _firstSet уже уничтожен.

Comment: А где коннекты сигналов temp2 к слотам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp2` расположен в стеке. Когда произойдет выход из конструктора `Cows`, объект `temp2` будет автоматически уничтожен => произойдут дисконнекты всех его сигналов.